# Retrieving ALL emails for ALL accounts from exchange server

Tags: exchange-server, imap

Is there a way to retrieve/download **ALL** emails for **ALL** user accounts from exchange server ? The crude way is to iterate through each user and retrieve there emails separately using IMAP. However I think that would be very inefficient and time consuming.

I know that on real time, we could use journaling feature to get all emails but how can I get access to the **all** existing emails on server for **all** accounts?

Thanks!

Comment: "inefficient and time consuming" - do you really think what you're doing is a *common* activity, that will have been optimized?

Comment: I know it isn't a common activity and I'll probably end up doing that if I don't find a better way. However I was trying to find out from experts if there is a better optimized way.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it's what you need. But an export fits also with your needs, if you have connection localy to the Exchange server. With Exchange 2007 you have this requirements, maybe in 2010 they have changed some of them.

- First you need to execute the exports script from a 32 bit Windows client.
- Exchange (32bits) tools installed
- Powershell, of course.
- Outlook installed.

#### Script to export mailboxes of all users

---

```
$users = Get-Mailbox | select alias
    
foreach ($user in $users)
{
# Just info
Get-MailboxStatistics -id $user.alias | select-object DisplayName,@{name='TotalItemSize(MB)';expression={$_.TotalItemSize/1MB}};
# Give rights to each mailbox, you can avoid this after first time
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity $user.alias -User "domain\adminuser" -AccessRights FullAccess;
# Export to the folder you want (should be mapped if remote)
Export-Mailbox -PSTFolderPath P:\psts\ -id $user.usuarios -Confirm:$False

}
```

---

Comment: Thanks Alfredo, let me give that a try and let you know how it goes.

BTW, how do you think a AV kind of solution does this? I'm assuming they also need to have access to ALL emails on server to be able to scan and report.

Comment: AV solutions plug into special virus scanning APIs in Exchange that give them access to this data.

Comment: Thanks Brian, that is good info. Technically, I could use the same APIs to get access to the ALL emails though I wouldn't be actually scanning them. Would that work? and do you know where I can find the spec for it?

Answer (score 0):

There's no native function to do this. IMAP is also not going to give you full fidelity. You could use impersonation with Exchange Web Services to hit each mailbox individually. If you want PSTs, the solution provided with `Export-Mailbox` on Exchange 2007 or `New-MailboxExportRequest` on Exchange 2010.